# Xamarin Forms: Design via XAML or backend code (C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Quick question about Xamarin.Forms;

Are their any advantages to design via XAML or via backend for designing your application? 
Or is it just preference?

I have seen many examples of people who are skilled in xamarin that are designing via code and less via XAML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is more of a preference. You can do everything in both.

The only thing you could argue is that when you use XAML with something like the MVVM pattern your design is separated from your logic which would makes it easier to implement another view at some point in the future.

This is why my preference is XAML. It just feels cleaner and more separated. Even more so I think it is easier to read than a whole lot of nested code constructions.

Also if in the (near) future more and better designers will come into play they will probably work only with XAML designed pages.

Check out this [Xamarin forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44117/xaml-vs-programmatically) for references with some more pros and cons.

Comment: Agree all all points! With the new forms designers just on the horizon, XAML (usually) makes more sense. Plus, you can always leverage the XAML Compiler to get the performance boost typically associated with C# layouts before you go to production: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/